# Is there any way to detect country phone code from google maps autocomplete api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-autocomplete

I am building a web app that requires to store the location of a client along with the phone number. I want the phone code to be auto-detected after location is selected. I have gone through the documentation of google maps provided in the following link but with no luck. 
[Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)
. Is there any way to detect phone code from google maps location?

Comment: Do you mean country phone code, or local codes also?

Comment: i mean only the country phone code

Comment: Is the API I gave below in reply OK?

Comment: the api is okay but only provides result for nepal's phonecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have identified the country you can go to an external API like `https://restcountries.eu` and retrieve data (including phone code) about any country.

For example `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/nepal?fullText=true` returns this JSON, where you can see the `callingCodes = 997`.

```
[{
    "name": "Nepal",
    "topLevelDomain": [".np"],
    "alpha2Code": "NP",
    "alpha3Code": "NPL",
    "callingCodes": ["977"],
    "capital": "Kathmandu",
    "altSpellings": ["NP", "Federal Democratic Republic of Nepal", "Loktāntrik Ganatantra Nepāl"],
    "region": "Asia",
    "subregion": "Southern Asia",
    "population": 28431500,
    "latlng": [28.0, 84.0],
    "demonym": "Nepalese",
    "area": 147181.0,
    "gini": 32.8,
    "timezones": ["UTC+05:45"],
    "borders": ["CHN", "IND"],
    "nativeName": "नेपाल",
    "numericCode": "524",
    "currencies": [{
        "code": "NPR",
        "name": "Nepalese rupee",
        "symbol": "₨"
    }],
    "languages": [{
        "iso639_1": "ne",
        "iso639_2": "nep",
        "name": "Nepali",
        "nativeName": "नेपाली"
    }],
    "translations": {
        "de": "Népal",
        "es": "Nepal",
        "fr": "Népal",
        "ja": "ネパール",
        "it": "Nepal",
        "br": "Nepal",
        "pt": "Nepal",
        "nl": "Nepal",
        "hr": "Nepal",
        "fa": "نپال"
    },
    "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/npl.svg",
    "regionalBlocs": [{
        "acronym": "SAARC",
        "name": "South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation",
        "otherAcronyms": [],
        "otherNames": []
    }],
    "cioc": "NEP"
}]
```

**EDIT:** Code added on request.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Get the phone code for Napal</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get Phone Code</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var locObj =  JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Phone Code for Napal = "+locObj[0].callingCodes;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/nepal?fullText=true", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Produces this output:

```
Phone Code for Napal = 977
```

Comment: so how do i extract the calling code from this response information?

Comment: Are you working in PHP or Javascript? The API returns a JSON array that can be parsed easily in those languages.

Comment: Ok I just posted some Javascript to show you how to extract the code from the JSON. You can put this in a html file and your browser can execute it.

Comment: Helpful or not?

Comment: for some reason this solution is only giving back the result of nepal as 977. for every other region it results in 246.
i am surprised how easily people degrade a solution (whoever did that). some solutions and questions may be the exact thing people are looking for.

Comment: I just changed one line to `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/ireland` and it correctly returned 353. Show me example which results in 246?

Comment: try the same for india

Comment: You are right. The India data seems wrong! I will check it some more ... maybe others are wrong also.

Comment: Ok Is fixed, See code above. You need to add `?fullText=true` as in `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/india?fullText=true`. Otherwise the response will include other countries that contain the search string.